# SQL Multiple Commands

Tags: sql, atomic

I am writing a method in C# which executes multiple SQL commands and returns a boolean value which determine if the insertions were successful or not. My problem is that I want to execute this command as an "all or nothing" command. This means that if I want to execute 3 different commands and the third command isn't executed correctly, the changes of the first two commands aren't committed. How can I do this in SQLServer please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41869/is-sql-server-bulk-insert-transactional this question discusses bulk inserts will rollbacks applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to execute the three commands from C#:

```
SqlTransaction tran = connection.BeginTransaction();
try
{
   ...exec first command and get result...
   ...exec second commmand and get result...
   ...exec third command and get result...
   if (!firstResult || !secondResult || !thirdResult)
      throw new Exception();

   tran.Commit();
}
catch
{
   tran.Rollback();
}
```

If you want to execute the three commands in SQL server by calling a stored procedure, then use:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

cmd1
cmd2
cmd3

IF @Success = 1 THEN
  COMMIT TRANSATION
ELSE
  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```

You can also use try..catch blocks in SQL to catch exceptions and rollback the transaction if an error occurs.

Comment: it just means that you should make a call to a procedure in sql or some insert/update query... it isn't a method or anything.

Comment: yes I know. so do you meanlike the `ExecuteNonQuery()` method?

Comment: yes. There is a good example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for a Transaction, which group many SQL queries (often INSERTS, UPDATES or DELETES) into one single unit of work, you should surround your querys with BEGIN TRAN (at the beginning) and COMMIT TRAN (at the end).
[SQL server transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913806/sql-server-transaction)